# October cms new administrator create

Tags: octobercms

When I create a new admin in October CMS, this error occurred. Can someone help me?

> "Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path
> specified. ]" on line 302 of
> C:\xampp\htdocs\october\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php

Comment: You need to post the code  for us to understand and provide any help

Comment: That error message usually means emailing is having an error. I see you are using xampp so it could be possible that you have not setup any way to email. When you create a new admin I believe you can uncheck the "Send Invitation Email" and it should create a new administrator as usually. You just need to configure your mail settings.

Answer (score 2):

After creating an administrator, an email is sent. You can set the mode of sending emails to `Log file` as described in the screenshot below or configure sending emails via SMTP

[image]